# Encode HTML to valid JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Given any valid HTML, how to encode it so that it is valid JSON? And later decode it so that you get back the same initial HTML.

`JSON.stringify` for encoding and `JSON.parse` seem to work well in my testing, but I could not find a definitive answer when researching this. I came across options like base64 (not a good option for anyone considering it, utf8 chars being one problem amongst others) and  `encodeURIComponent`.

This seems like such a common task that I expected to find a "this is the one 'right/best' way to do this".

As for why I want to do this: GraphQL is quickly becoming the way of things. It communicates in JSON. Any GraphQL API based app that for example wants to allow users to say write a comment or post in html...will need to pass around html in json.

**Note:** don't assume we are getting the HTML from the DOM. We may be getting it from a database, an API request, a rich text editor (our current use case), anywhere. So  just assume we have some HTML e.g. `<p>This is <b>bold</b> text</p>` but it can be *any* valid HTML -- various tags, character sets, etc.

Comment: `This seems like such a common task`...not really. Why would you need to encode HTML as JSON? HTML is effectively already a data format of sorts. What exact format would you expect? They don't automatically map well onto each other.

Comment: @ADyson passing html around in API calls? For example, an app where a user can leave a rich text comment. GraphQL API call to store this comment in a database, so the comment can be read by other users. (and I'm not sure why someone would downvote this....I explained the question pretty clearly, I think)

Comment: HTML is a string, so the answer is the same as "How do you encode a string in JSON?"

Comment: If it's not coming from the DOM, it's just a string. Base64 isn't a bad solution to make it easier/safer to put into a JSON field. You can also URL safe base64 encode.

Comment: @TheFool base64 can't handle things like  which are pretty common in user comments

Comment: Or just `JSON.stringify(htmlString)`. There's no need for further encoding. It will handle anything that can be represented in a JavaScript string.

Comment: @KayakinKoder it can. This is your emoji as base64 `8J+Yigo=`.

Comment: @TheFool correct, but first you must decode the . If that is the best way to get html into json -- first decoding, then base64-ing, by all means submit an answer. I'm aware it's possible.

Comment: @KayakinCoder in the API scenario the comment text would likely be the value of a property of an object that you submit to the API containing the comment itself and probably a bit of metadata I imagine. So you'd encode the whole object as JSON. The fact that the comment text happens to contain HTML isn't really relevant to that process. As others have said, in that context it's just a piece of text. Unless you have an example which demonstrates otherwise?

Comment: I have not decoded this. I have just piped the emoji into base64.  `echo  | base64`. So you *encode* it, and then you put it into JSON. It's not uncommon, since base64 can be handled more easy than all sorts of special characters.

Comment: @ADyson "So you'd encode the whole object as JSON". Correct. "The fact that the comment text happens to contain HTML isn't really relevant to that process." Then explain why that's true in an answer. It seems relevant to me, but if it's not that's great. I can encode just as I should encode anything else.

Comment: @TheFool `echo` you seem to be doing this in php. My question is for a javascript environment. If you think that's the correct way to do things, by all means submit an answer.

Comment: this was just in my terminal using bash. Any langauge can do that...

Comment: I've just explained why...it's text, like any other text. It's up to you to demonstrate a specific issue where you're trying to do something involving that and it's not working as you wanted. FWIW I didn't downvote, but so far your question seems somewhat speculative and attempting to solve a problem you haven't clearly defined and/or haven't actually experienced. It might even be an XY problem, but we'd need to see a concrete example of an issue, so we can explain how to solve it.

Comment: Good JSON package will handle your quotes just fine. Alternatively, I have already told you that you could encode it with base64 to make it more tool friendly.

Comment: For example `JSON.stringify('<a href="google.com">google</a>')` returns this `"<a href=\"google.com\">google</a>"`, so you see it knows how to escape the quotes.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412207).

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with elements, you can simply serialize it by getting its [`outerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

```js
function serialize(element){
  return {html: element.outerHTML};
}

function parse(html){
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = html.html;
  return temp.firstChild;
}

const serialized = serialize(div)

console.log('serialized:', serialized)

const parsed = parse(serialized)

console.log('parsed:', parsed)
```

```html
<div id="div">Hello World!</div>
```

If the element in question is passed as a string, you can parse it first:

```js
function serialize(element){
  return {html: element.outerHTML ? element.outerHTML : parse({html: element}).outerHTML};
}

function parse(html){
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = html.html;
  return temp.firstChild;
}

const serialized = serialize("<p>This is <b>bold</b> text</p>")

console.log('serialized:', serialized)

const parsed = parse(serialized)

console.log('parsed:', parsed)
```